# Python Polars crashes in parallel with s.__getstate__() not implemented

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, runtime-error, python-polars

I have a function that iterates over the rows in a polars dataframe and applies some manipulation to it. I know that `iter_rows()` should be avoided, but let it be for this usecase. I want to split the dataframe I am iterating over into multiple parts, apply the function in parralel, collect the results in a shared `multiprocessing.Queue` and append them to each other again after everything is finished.
My multiprocessing setup looks like this looks like this:

```
import polars as pl
import multiprocessing as mp

import src.polar_utils as pu
from tests import get_test_dict


DICT: pl.DataFrame = get_test_df("test_df_2")["test_df_2"]
PUB_DF: pl.DataFrame = get_test_df("test_df_1")["test_df_1"]

queue = mp.Queue()
n_threads = 4
DICT = DICT.filter(pl.col("IdA").is_null())
dict_splits = pu.split_uniform_rowwise(df=DICT, n_chunks=n_threads)
processes = [
    mp.get_context("spawn").Process(
        target=myfunc1,
        kwargs={
            "d1": PUB_DF,
            "d2": dict_splits[i],
            "queue": queue,
        }
    )
    for i in range(n_threads)
]
[p.start() for p in processes]
results = []
while True:
    running = any(p.is_alive() for p in processes)
    while not queue.empty():
        results.append(queue.get())
    if not running:
        break
[p.join() for p in processes]
while len(results) > 0:
    print(results.pop(0))
```

The function `myfunc1` looks like this:

```
import polars as pl

def mfunc1(
    d1: pl.DataFrame, d2: pl.DataFrame, aff_column="Affiliations", queue=None
) -> pl.DataFrame:
    i = 0
    for (id,) in d2.select("IdE").iter_rows():
        d1 = d1.with_columns(
            pl.col(aff_column)
            .str.extract_all(re.escape(id))
            .list.unique()
            .list.lengths()
            .alias(f"{aff_column}_{i}")
            == 1
        )
        i += 1
        print(i, end="\r")
    d1 = (
        d1.with_columns(matches=pl.concat_list(pl.col("^" + aff_column + "_[0-9]+$")))
        .drop(pl.selectors.matches("^" + aff_column + "_[0-9]+$"))
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("matches").apply(lambda x: list(compress(range(len(x)), x)))
        )
        .with_columns(pl.col("matches").list.lengths().alias("n_matches"))
        .filter(pl.col("n_matches") >= 0)
    )

    if queue:
        queue.put(d1)
        return
    return d1
```

Sorry that this still looks quiet complicated, I was not able to reproduce the error with a simpler example. I already simplified `myfunc1`so that right now it does not really do anything useful, but it raises the following error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'not implemented', /Users/runner/work/polars/polars/crates/polars-core/src/serde/series.rs:66:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Exception in thread QueueFeederThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/Users/malte/Documents/bibinstident/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/series/series.py", line 435, in __getstate__
    return self._s.__getstate__()
```

What exactly means that `s.__getstate__()` is not implemented for `Series` and how does it relate to my code?
Another note: You can see that in `myfunc1` I am modifying `d1` multiple times in the loop and again in the assignment after the loop. If I do only one of the two, so either only the loop or only the assignment later, everything seems to work fine.

I appreciate any help or information how this error occurs and what I should do to avoid it. Thanks! :)

Comment: As for how it is related: `.__getstate__()` is used by pickle, multiprocessing uses pickle. It's essentially impossible to debug the current example: `pu.split_uniform_rowwise` appears to be from a custom library? As for the approach: is there a reason you can't use Polars as-is and allow it to handle the parallelism instead of using multiprocessing?

Comment: Polars Series do support pickle. Have you got an older version running? 

And why do you try to parallelize polars? Polars will likely run much faster if you let it decide how to parallelize.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hints, @ritchie46 I saw that my version was 0.18.14, I upgraded to 0.18.15 but that did not change anything. Well if I split the dataframe that is iterated over into let's say 4 parts, and the loops in each thread only have to to 1/4 of the work, the program does actually run 4x faster. (If I use a version of the function that does not produce the error). So I think parallelizing the loop does make sense.

Comment: @jqurious I was not able to come up with a logic in "pure" polars that does the required thing without `iter_rows()`, but that's maybe a question for another thread. Yes, `split_uniform_rowwise` is from a custom library and just splits a DataFrame `df` into `n_chunks` dataframes of appr. equal height.

Comment: Okay, I found out that I just have to comment out the line `.with_columns(
            pl.col("matches").apply(lambda x: list(compress(range(len(x)), x)))
        )` to make it work. I think I will just move that part outside of `myfunc1`. Is this behaviour intended or would it not be desirerable that an `apply`call should also work when executed simultanously in multiple threads, given that they are applied to different DataFrames? Maybe this information is somewhat useful to somebody.

Comment: Are you really running `itertools.compress` inside `.apply` or is this just some placeholder example? It's probably more productive if you show the actual goal/task as the substring count example should be possible using native Polars functionality. The reason multiprocessing offers a speedup here is because you're using `.apply`. Using `.apply` causes Polars to execute Python code sequentially (slow) - but if you don't use `.apply` in the first place Polars will execute Rust code in parallel (fast).

Comment: Thanks @jqurious, I opened a question for my original problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76961836/17099286