# Python Polars match lists of patterns on every row

Tags: python, dataframe, pattern-matching, python-polars

I have a `polars.DataFrame` `Strings`:

```
| Strings                     |
-------------------------------
| "Apples are red"            |
| "Apples are not Bananas"    |
| "Bananas are not red"       |
| "I like Apples and Bananas" |
| "Oranges are kinda red"     |
-------------------------------
```

and another `DataFrame` `Patterns`:

```
| Patterns              │ 
-------------------------
| ["Bananas", "red"]    |
| ["Apples"]            |
| ["Apples", "Bananas"] |
-------------------------
```

I want to match every pattern in `Patterns` against every string in `Strings`. That the
`Pattern`s are given in list form means, that **all** words from the list have to be found in order to consider the list to be found. The result should therefore look something like this:

```
| Strings                     | matches_index | matches                            |
|-----------------------------|---------------|------------------------------------|
| "Apples are red"            | [1]           | [["Apples"]]                       |
| "Apples are not Bananas"    | [1, 2]        | [["Apples"], ["Apples", "Bananas"]]|
| "Bananas are not red"       | [0]           | [["Bananas", "red"]]               |
| "I like Apples and Bananas" | [1, 2]        | [["Apples"], ["Apples", "Bananas"]]|
| "Oranges are kinda red"     | []            | []                                 |
```

---

Right now my solution is to iterate over the patterns, concatenate each list with `|`, use
`extract_all` for the concatenated pattern and check if the number of unique matches equals the length of the original pattern list. That works but maybe somebody has an idea how to implement this in native polars (without `iter_rows()` over the patterns).

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add the code for your current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = (
    df_str.join(df_pat.with_row_count('match_index'), how='cross')
    .explode('Patterns')
    .with_columns(contains=pl.col('Strings').str.contains(pl.col('Patterns')))
    .groupby('Strings', 'match_index')
    .all()
    .filter(pl.col('contains').list.all())
    .groupby('Strings')
    .agg(pl.exclude('contains'))
    .join(df_str, on='Strings', how='outer')
)
```

Overall approach:

- make a cross join `df`, that is every row of one dataframe with every row of another dataframe
- the [`with_row_count`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_count.html#polars.DataFrame.with_row_count) on the `pat`tern dataframe gives us all possible `match_index`es out of the box
- [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode) the `Patterns` lists at this time so each element is on its own row, with other data duplicated per row.
- Create a temporary column, `contains`, that does the actual regex matching.
- "implode" back to lists with a `groupby` and `all` (syntactic sugar for `agg(pl.all())`).
- Finally ready to do the `filter` which is now straightforward with the temp column.
- `groupby` again and aggregate to final lists, this time without the temp column.
- (More optional) recover any strings with no matches, one final outer join on the original strings dataframe.

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Strings                   ┆ match_index ┆ Patterns                            │
│ ---                       ┆ ---         ┆ ---                                 │
│ str                       ┆ list[u32]   ┆ list[list[str]]                     │
╞═══════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Apples are red            ┆ [1]         ┆ [["Apples"]]                        │
│ Apples are not Bananas    ┆ [2, 1]      ┆ [["Apples", "Bananas"], ["Apples"]] │
│ Bananas are not red       ┆ [0]         ┆ [["Bananas", "red"]]                │
│ I like Apples and Bananas ┆ [1, 2]      ┆ [["Apples"], ["Apples", "Bananas"]] │
│ Oranges are kinda red     ┆ null        ┆ null                                │
└───────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The order of the lists can be forced with `maintain_order=True` on the `groupby`s, but that is slower.